# Problem with Rest - Sharepoint Online - Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

If I tried run Rest Functionality I have got Problem with Autentyfication on Sharepoint Designer and Sharepoint Online. What could be a problem. How could I fix this ? Is the secure Store configure will help me ?

Comment: Try to run the same REST call from the browser and see the response. There are no settings required for default SharePoint REST Api service and these are run with user context.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the reconditions from this Stack thread on the same issue. 
[SharePoint online - login issue with designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126116/sharepoint-online-login-issue-with-designer)