# SharePoint Designer 2013 : There is a problem with your account please try again later

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365

I know this is a repeat question but i am unable to find any meaningful links that address this issue. 
I am trying to open SharePoint Online site with my designer but I am getting below error when i sign in:

There is a problem with your account please try again later

Can anyone please let me know the possible cause of this issue.
We are using Office 365 Enterprise E3 plan.

Comment: Assuming you can login using web browser, can you check if there is any error reported in Event Logs? This usually happens due to firewall or proxy in your organisation. Try connecting from home network and see if it works.

Comment: Good suggestion, i will try to connect from home network. I am checking logs under Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application, is this the right location to find for logs ?

Comment: In most cases, its correct Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application

Comment: Try to run SharePoint Designer with Administrator permission

Comment: I was unable to find any warnings or error in Event viewer. Even tried Run as Administrator still same issue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue when i connect from home network. I am confident my password is not expired nor reset. Any idea on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Try clearing SharePoint designer cache http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/

Answer (score 3):

I was able resolve this for myself by removing Registry keys provided in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136373/there-is-a-problem-with-your-account-please-try-again-later-error-when): HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Identity
FederationCacheExpiration 
FederationProvider

And adding this one suggested in this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-Modern-Authentication-for-Office-2013-on-Windows-devices-7dc1c01a-090f-4971-9677-f1b192d6c910): HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Identity
Add Dword EnableADAL 1

I also deleted the cache, tried run as admin, uninstall and reinstall and none of that worked until also updating the registry keys

Comment: Hi again! Same as my other comment, please consider summarizing the content in the links so we don't lose the info if they get broken. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: I received a new computer and all the steps I used last time to fix this issue did not fix it this time. After 2 hours of editing registry and rebooting, I decided to try something else. Went to IE (will not work in any other browser), opened up the site, went to edit page in Designer and it opened without prompting me to login.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was related to **two-factor** authentication. I solve it by generating *app password* on page https://portal.office.com/account. When you generate this unique password phrase then just use it instead you original password.

Comment: I couldn't find that option under the provided link, but this one works: [https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/AppPasswords.aspx](https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/AppPasswords.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Install SPD SP1 and it should work. Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joerg_sinemus/2017/03/03/sharepoint-designer-2013-and-login-issue-in-cloud-scenario/#comment-8375

Comment: It worked for me - but 64 bit was recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Also wanted to add, my resolution was to remove my Office 365 account attached to Windows 10 in the Access Work or School. It seems to cause authentication issues occassionally. Immediately after removing the account was able to sign in without issue.